# Setting the Default TextBox.Value TypeName in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba function that checks if a user-input from a text box is positive integer or not. The code below:

```
Public Function IsPosInteger(n As Variant) As Boolean  
    If IsNumeric(n) = True Then
        If (n = Int(n)) And n > 0 Then
            IsPosInteger = True
        Else
            IsPosInteger = False
        End If
    Else
        IsPosInteger = False
End If
End Function
```

The problem is that upon testing the function still returns false for a valid positive integer. Upon further investigation, I noticed that the variable type by default for texbox values is String. Probably the main reason why IsNumeric is returning false.

Function below is what I used to determine the type of the variable.

```
TypeName(n)
```

Comment: Convert the input to a `Long` value instead of an `Integer` using `CLng(n)`.

Comment: Make sure your decimal-seperator is . and not a , Isnumeric will be true on a number even when it's type is a string. Your function should work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

I used an inputbox that contained:

- strings (False)
- negative numbers (False)
- positive numbers (true)
- positive numbers and letters (false)

```
Public Function IsPosInteger(n As Variant) As Boolean
    If n > 0 And IsNumeric(n) Then IsPosInteger = True
End Function
```

---

Now, the other issue may arise that the value `n` is still technically type **String** due to the nature of the inputbox -- even if it passes the test of this function. *If you wish to change this behavior*, continue reading.

To do this, ensure that you are using `ByRef` *(when this is **intentional**, I usually type out `ByRef` on the argument, even though it is automatically assumed by VBA that any argument passed to a function is `ByRef` if it doesn't explicitly state `ByVal`)*.

If this is the outcome you are wanting, then you can use this function:

```
Public Function IsPosInteger(ByRef n As Variant) As Boolean
    If n > 0 And IsNumeric(n) Then 
        IsPosInteger = True
        n = clng(n) '<-- This converts the variant (currently a string) n to type long,
                    '    only if it passes the test
    end if
End Function
```

You must ensure that `n` in the calling routine is of type `Variant`, else you will encounter an error.

Comment: thanks for responding to this query. How will I integrate input box to my text box which is placed in a user form?

Comment: @olbinado11 you should be able to simply replace your function with this one without requiring any additional changes.

Comment: These functions will return true if the user enters a decimal value. You need to test for that as well if you want only integer input.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function IsPosInteger(s As String) As Boolean 'boolean data type is false by default.
    If (IsNumeric(s) = False) Then Exit Function
    If (s < 1) Then Exit Function
    If (InStr(s, ".") = False) Then IsPosInteger = True
End Function
```

Function tests that the input is numeric, not less than 1, and does not contain a decimal. Here is an example of how you could use it in your calling sub:

```
Sub TestInput()
    Dim sUserInput As String
    Dim boolPositiveInt As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    sUserInput = Range("A1").Value2
    boolPositiveInt = IsPosInteger(sUserInput)
    If (boolPositiveInt = False) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = CInt(sUserInput)
    'continue working with integer variable here
End Sub
```